# Flat and faithful (as functor) implies faithfully flat

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I'm trying to understand the proof of $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$
in [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HO) lemma in The Stack Project.

But I couldn't follow the argument. **How could I see $\alpha \otimes \mathrm{id}_M$ is zero by the exactness of the complex $-\otimes_R M$?** Can you give me some hints? Thanks
[image]

Comment: The title is misleading as there is a notion of a faithful module (zero annihilator), but it's not true that a faithful and flat module is faithfully flat

Comment: @LukasHeger Thanks, I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\alpha\otimes id_M: R\otimes_R M\to N_2/Im(N_1)\otimes_R M$$ sending $$\alpha\otimes id_M(r\otimes  m)=\alpha(r)\otimes m=(rx+Im(N_1))\otimes m.$$

$rx\otimes m\in N_2\otimes_R M$ such that under the map $N_2\otimes_R M\to N_3\otimes_R M$ it maps $rx\otimes m\mapsto 0$.

So there is $\beta=\sum n_i\otimes m_i \in N_1\otimes M$ such that $\beta\mapsto rx\otimes m$ under the map $f_1\otimes id_M: N_1\otimes_R M\to N_2\otimes_R M$.

So
$rx\otimes m=(f_1\otimes id_M)(\beta)=\sum f_1(n_i)\otimes m_i\in N_2\otimes M$ so that under the map $$N_2\otimes M\to N_2/Im(N_1)\otimes_R M$$

$$rx\otimes m\mapsto 0$$

Hence $\alpha\otimes id_M(r\otimes  m)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write $f:N_1\to N_2$ and $g: N_2\to N_3$.
The functor $-\otimes_R M$ preserves cokernels and there is a map
$$\ker(g)\otimes_R M \to \ker(g\otimes 1),$$
and then $\alpha\otimes 1$ is obtained by looking at the composition

$$\ker(g)\otimes_R M \to \ker(g\otimes 1) \subseteq N_2\otimes_R M \to \operatorname{coker}(f\otimes 1) = \operatorname{coker}(f)\otimes_R M.$$

Now $\ker(g\otimes 1) = \operatorname{im}(f\otimes 1)$ since the tensored sequence is exact, which means that each of its elements has zero class in $\operatorname{coker}(f\otimes 1)$. This shows that $\alpha\otimes 1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$rx\in \ker(N_2\longrightarrow N_3)=\operatorname{Im}N_1 $.

Comment: This is what the OP wants to show...?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: That's  the starting point to understand why $\alpha\otimes 1=0$.